# while removing php extention in url it's not loading css files

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I'm trying to removing php extention and customize url it's working url but not loading css file..
i change this url: http://localhost/rozgar/jobs.php?search=testing

To this formate: http://localhost/rozgar/jobs/testing

Here is my .htaccess code.

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^jobs/([A-Za-z]+) jobs.php?search=$1
```

Css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- MAIN CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
```

htm code..how to get this url **http://localhost/rozgar/jobs/testing** when user click on submit button

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="get" action="jobs">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search By Job, Company, Category...">
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2" id="padd">
            <select id="dropDesign" name="city" class="form-control">
              <option value="" selected disabled>Select City</option>
              <?php
                $query="select * from city";
                $rs=mysqli_query($db,$query);

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
                  $city = $row[1];

              ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $city; ?>" name="city"><?php echo $city; ?></option>
              <?php
            }
            ?>
            </select>
          </div>
```

Comment: Show us the `<link rel ... />` for the stylesheet, please.

Comment: A stab in the dark (since you haven't shown us the css link where your issue actually is), change your links to your css (and all other resources) to relative paths from the document root. Example: `href="/path/to/stylesheet.css"`. The initial slash makes the link relative from the document root.

Comment: I don't know it's problem with css loading or something else.. because content loading working fine but without design

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">` < that's your problem; you've changed the URL so that instead of the *working directory* being `/rozgar` it's now `/rozgar/jobs` so `../` is looking for the CSS file in `/rozgar/css` rather than `/css` ... as @MagnusEriksson suggested - remove the `..` from the `href`s so they're like `/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: As MagnusEriksson & CD001 suggested, it can be either "/css/bootstrap.min.css" or "http://localhost/rozgar/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Comment: Thanks it's now workng, but now problem is I'm using get method in form and how to customize url when user click on search box button? when user click on button it show this url http://localhost/rozgar/jobs.php?search=testing

Comment: You _always_ need to show us your code for us to be able to help you. Show us the forms action tag.